# Is drawing pictures in books prohibited?

Tags: halal-haram, fiqh, image, drawing

I know that it is not allowed to put pictures of people, characters, etc. on walls, or any visible places, but, what about in notebooks or papers for fun?

Comment: practical query! Actually, it doesn't seem to be deemed as a haram act if you don't draw by a negative intention (such as create..) and meanwhile if the pics are permissible and don't mock people ...

Answer (score 2):

Assalaamu alaikum warehmatullahi wabarakatuhu, 
In the name of Allah, the most Gracious, the most Merciful

There seems to be two issues, but regarding your issue:-
Abû Talhah relates that the Prophet (peace be upon him) said: “The angels do not enter a house wherein there is a dog or images representing (people or animals).” [Sahîh al-Bukhârî (3225) and Sahîh Muslim (2106)]

I purchased a cushion with pictures on it. The Prophet (came and) stood at the door but did not enter. I said (to him), "I repent to Allah for what (the guilt) I have done." He said, "What is this cushion?" I said, "It is for you to sit on and recline on." He said, "The makers of these pictures will be punished on the Day of Resurrection and it will be said to them, 'Make alive what you have created.' Moreover, the angels do not enter a house where there are pictures.'" (Narrated by Ayesha).
Hadith 7.843 (Al-Bukhari hadith)

And regarding that you want to draw them:
`A’ishah relates that the Prophet (peace be upon him) said: “The people who will be most severely punished on the Day of Resurrection will be those who aspire to create like Allah.” [Sahîh al-Bukhârî (5954) and Sahîh Muslim (2107)] 
When we look at the phrase – “those who aspire to create like Allah” – the term “aspire” here indicates a challenge. It means that these image makers are fashioning images in order to imitate Allah’s creative abilities and to present a challenge to Allah.

If we look at the statements of the Pious Predecessors, we can see that they understood the texts about image making to be merely a severe warning against what is sinful rather than a direct prohibition. For instance, when a man who was a professional image maker came to Ibn `Abbâs asking him for a ruling, Ibn`Abbâs merely said: “If you have to do so, then make images of trees and of that which has no soul. [Sahîh al-Bukhârî (2225) and Sahîh Muslim (2110)]

My conclusion is that you can keep drawings, posters, images inside books and papers (as long as it is not put to display or left open, laying around). Concluding that you can not imitate Allah's creation (By drawing them).

For more detail on drawing humans or animals go through my question page, I had asked a similar/relating question.! :)

Comment: Can I draw a full human body though? I used to draw Chibi-like things (search chibi on Google), that's why.

Comment: A figure without a face is acceptable.

Comment: What about ones with face or drawing just the face?

Comment: Faces itself are not allowed, as it mentions in the hadiths above.... U cannot imitate the creation of Allah, it was mentioned by a scholar that the head is the identity if that is cut off (not drawn or not present/visible) then it is not similar to the creation.

Comment: @Muslim But what about if you are drawing but not in the intention or not try to imitate Allah's creation? Also not on the face is Allah's creation so shouldn't the ruling apply to every creation? If it is only things with a soul then shouldn't be the whole body not just face? Also does this apply to photos and films too?

Comment: You should draw in the intention not to copy the Almighty's creation indeed as well as not to draw it either. Yes every animal, human beings, fishes etc. I did mention about drawing the parts of the body or whole body without the head/face! Mentioned in my previous comment, a body is incomplete without it's identity (face/head).

Comment: About photographs and films, videos etc, they are recorded by a system application you are not the one personally tracing the image it is captured in a film, but as long as you keep it hidden or unseen it is fine! In short you can not draw a complete figure of any soul oriented creation (except a part of it or without head/face) but can take pictures of them.